# Unable To set row visible false of a datagridview

Tags: c#

I had a DatagridView
I had set its datasource From A class

```
taskerEntities te = new taskerEntities();
var OMsMasterDescriptiveIndicators = te.MyTable.Select(x => new lccls {Id = x.Id, name = x.name }).ToList();
MyGrid.DataSource = OMsMasterDescriptiveIndicators;
```

My Class is Like

```
public class lccls
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> name { get; set; }
    }
```

At a certain event i want to Visible false The Current Row

```
 MyGrid.Rows[5].Visible = false;
```

But I am unable To do this because i think the reason Is It's `datasource` associated 
So can you Please help me how Could I do this and Whatever I think About This Problem Is correct Or not
The Error is

> Row associated with the currency manager's position cannot be made
>   invisible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is

```
 CurrencyManager currencyManager1 = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[MyGrid.DataSource];
    currencyManager1.SuspendBinding();
    MyGrid.Rows[5].Visible = false;
    currencyManager1.ResumeBinding();
```